# Does sharepoint upload API supports split batch?

Tags: sharepoint

my application is web site, front－end use silverlight, upload file to share point server to store, file may be large, e.g. 500M, need split parts to upload, e.g. at first, upload 10M of a 500M file to share point server, stop or network broken，then upload rest 10M of the file to server, and so on, till complete.

if API don't support this, how to do?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a file upload is broken in any of SharePoint API's the item is thrown away, any implementation like that needs to be handled by your silverlight implementation.

If you want to develop such functionality there are a few different ways to go, consider developing an extra layer (in example a self hosted webservice) that your silverlight site connects and sends it's file to, when sent to the webservice the service will chunk the file and send it in parts to sharepoint.

`Silverlight <-> Self hosted web service <-> SharePoint`